# Import and append pickle files

Tags: python, for-loop, import, append, pickle

How could I import and append all files in a directory?

```
files = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\arv\Desktop\pickle_files")
data = []
for i in files:
    data.append(pd.read_pickle(i)) 
df = pd.concat(['data'])
```

Comment: `['data']` is a list of one string "data". Should be simply `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost like you tried to do it yourslf:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(f) for f in files])
```